# SSRS Recursive Parent: Limit number of Children

Tags: recursion, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, recursive-query, ssrs-tablix

I have an ssrs recursive parent report. It is working fine and I can easily collapse and drop my data using the +/- button. My problem is that some of the parents have way too many children. Is there any way to limit the number of shown children? On a perfect scenario, I'd like to show for example 3 of the children and then put 3 dots like "..." as the last child so the user knows there are more data but not shown.
I would like to achieve something like this(Of course, parents are going to be collapsible ):
[image]

I appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: Add a filter to your table and  select top N option from the operator dropdown.

Comment: @Snowlockk Thanks for your reply. Sounds like a good idea. But is there any way to do it on the report side?

Comment: @Snowlockk Ok, I can see i can add the filter on the report as well, but hwo can I apply the filter to the children only? I have a head employee and up to 4 levels they can have employees than work under them.